# Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting on Ubuntu

Tags: ios, ubuntu, build

I tried reinstalling `ideviceinstaller` and `usbmuxd` but the following command does not seems to work.

> ideviceinstaller -i myfile.ipa

I have also tried changing permission for lockdown folder

> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/lockdown

It does not help either.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ would be a better forum for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu covers more general issues.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Answer (score 1):

A recent change to libimobiledevice bumped the constraint on libusbmuxd to >= version 1.1.0. The current usbmuxd homebrew package is version 1.0.10.

As a result, homebrew --HEAD installs of libimobiledevice no longer build without a --HEAD install of usbmuxd.

Workaround is to install it at HEAD:

```
brew update
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew unlink usbmuxd
brew link usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
```

Comment: This is on Ubuntu, so he probably got libimobiledevice via apt-get, not brew.